# Delete WFFM Report record

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

When I select a WFFM from and open the form report and try to delete one of the records the following error appears:

[SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'dbo.SplitIds'.]

Is this object a missing table or stored procedure?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like one of WFFM functions absents on your installation. Do you have access to your WFFM SQL database?

If yes, can you please check it within functions folder for that database:

[image]

That is your missing function **dbo.SplitIds** .

If that is the only database object missing on your instance and you do not have  it anywhere else, you may use this script which will re-create it back. Do not forget **USE**  prior:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitIds]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @IdValues nvarchar(max),
    @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(1) = ','
)
RETURNS 
@IDs TABLE 
(
    Id uniqueidentifier not null
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Separator nvarchar(1)
    SET @Separator  = @Delimiter

    DECLARE @Iterator int
    SET @Iterator = 1

    DECLARE @RowData NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @RowData = @IdValues

    DECLARE @FoundIndex INT
    SET @FoundIndex = CHARINDEX(@Separator,@RowData)

    WHILE (@FoundIndex>0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @IDs (Id)
        SELECT          Data = dbo.Trim(SUBSTRING(@RowData, 1, @FoundIndex - 1))

        SET @RowData = SUBSTRING(@RowData, @FoundIndex + DATALENGTH(@Separator) / 2,  LEN(@RowData))

        SET @Iterator = @Iterator + 1   
        SET @FoundIndex = CHARINDEX(@Separator, @RowData)
    END

    INSERT INTO @IDs (Id)
    SELECT Data = dbo.Trim(@RowData)

    RETURN 
END
```

After the function is back, try deleting your report(s) again. If that was the only one missing function - that will work, if not - then it will tell you what else is missing.
Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes the above function was missing and also the below [dbo].[Trim] function